# Which Frameworks are used to access Mac or windows PC from iPhone from a different place or remotley

Tags: iphone, vnc

In my project i want to access my Mac remotely through my iPhone. i.e, like we can access other systems by using our system using **gotomeeting**  software like that, in the same way i have to access Mac through iPhone.

To achieve this which frameworks or what approach i have to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices.

Bonjour will allow you to create a localized peer-to-peer network. You can run the web server off the Mac and PC and let the iPhone get information that way. You can use bluetooth functionality in some cases.

See "[Getting Started with Networking and Internet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/)" and the ["Network" section of the iPhone Application Programming Guide."](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW26)